# Filename by join string in Python

Tags: php, python

I have a simple code line in Python, use too many `+` is not nice

```
filename = path + '/static/' + folder + '/' + name + 'html'
```

Can be like that in `php`

```
$filename = "$path/static/$folder/{$name}html"
```

So how we write shorten in `Python`?

Comment: @starkeen: `Improved formatting` i cannot see what have just edited? it seems as same as before.

Comment: see [revisions side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35967925/revisions#)

Comment: Please try searching on the internet before asking a question. Google is your best friend.

Comment: @user3100115 i did, but cannot see what's changed, since these lines are in code blocks before edited.

Comment: click on `side-by-side markdown` link

Comment: @MrPyCharm what is keyword to search this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in python which would be much more readable,

```
filename = "{}/static/{}/{}html".format(path, folder, name)
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want is join the path components. To do this you can use the [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) function which uses `os.sep` as separator.

```
>>> import os
>>> path = 'workspace'
>>> folder = 'stackoverflow'
>>> name = 'layout'
>>> os.path.join(path, 'static', folder, name, 'html')
'workspace/static/stackoverflow/layout/html'
```

You can also use [`PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths) if you are using Python 3.4 or newer.

```
from pathlib import PurePath

p = PurePath(path)
filename = str(p / static / folder / name / 'html')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pathlib import PurePath
>>> p = PurePath(path)
>>> filename = str(p / 'static' / folder / name / 'html')
>>> filename
'workspace/static/stackoverflow/layout/html'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.join` because it will work on all operating systems